# Xbox 360 displays a strange screen and wont open

Tags: technical-issues, xbox-360

My Xbox 360 won't open, a strange screen is appearing (attached image), I unplugged all cables but it won’t work.

[image: weird squiggly lines on a grey screen]

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: Is the TV itself fine? Have you swapped cables?

Comment: With 'my Xbox 360 won't open' you mean its disk tray?

Answer (score -3):

It might be broken. This happened to my father: he gave it to GameStop and they said it was completely broken, but maybe you're lucky and it can be repaired.

Comment: Okay, that's possible.  But how does that fix the issue?

Comment: Can you identify what exactly had been broken? Did you or your father try to fix the problem? Did Gamestop give any feedback? At this point, this is too broad an answer to be helpful.

Comment: no he got rid of it im mad he did not even try to fix it